# How to set pin-1 for Python in Ubuntu 22?

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, python, versions

I tried to install [pharokka](https://github.com/gbouras13/pharokka#installation) on Ubuntu 22.04. I first tried with conda, as suggested, then mamba, again as suggested. But the installation did not go through. I tried to install from source but I need to install the dependencies indicated. The first dependency was bcbio-gff, but during the installation from conda (`conda install bcbio-gff`) I got the error:

```
$ conda install bcbio-gff
Channels:
 - conda-forge
 - bioconda
 - defaults
Platform: linux-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: / warning  libmamba Added empty dependency for problem type SOLVER_RULE_UPDATE
failed

LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
  - package bcbio-gff-0.6.2-py_0 requires bx-python, but none of the providers can be installed

Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
├─ bcbio-gff is installable and it requires
│  └─ bx-python with the potential options
│     ├─ bx-python [0.10.0|0.8.13|0.9.0] would require
│     │  └─ python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0 , which can be installed;
...
└─ pin-1 is not installable because it requires
   └─ python 3.11.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.

Pins seem to be involved in the conflict. Currently pinned specs:
 - python 3.11.* (labeled as 'pin-1')
```

I got the same error with `conda install bx-python` so I installed python 3.12 (`conda install python=3.12`) since I though it was more advanced than 3.11, but now I get the error:

```
...
└─ pin-1 is not installable because it requires
   └─ python 3.12.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.

Pins seem to be involved in the conflict. Currently pinned specs:
 - python 3.12.* (labeled as 'pin-1')
```

Thus, I thin the error was not in the version of python but on something upstream.

How can I install these packages properly? How can I solve this pin-1 problem? What is pin-1 in the first place?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try adding python=3.10 in command line

conda install bcbio-gff python=3.10